# How to escape special characters in URL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm confused queries with string where's contains some special characters like & % $ # not validated.I've tried with `urlencode, htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, mysql_real_escape_string` but nothing.URLs not opened with this strings.

In this way I've insert into database:

```
$name = @$_POST["name"];    
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO article SET
                           name='$name',
                           description='$description',
                           html='$html' ");

***From Form*** - <input type="text" name="name">
```

And Regex:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([^/\*]+)/?$ /index.php?page=article&name=$1 [L]
```

If I use `$name = htmlentities or htmlspecialchars(@$_POST["name"]);`

With query string for e.g. - Article &number1

In database inserted and encoded as `Article &amp;number1`

Comment: Use [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).

Comment: I've have column name in my table.From name column I've get the string that is used for title therefore it's the url.

Comment: give some example so problem can be found

Comment: Even %26 which is encoded from & not working on URL.